# How can I pass an argument between fragments with databinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to pass an argument from one fragment to another to use the argument on the label of the new fragement.
I have a recyclerView with dates, I put the dayID as the argument on Navigation but I don't know how to put it on the dataBinding to retrieve it on the next fragment.
Also, after retrieving it, how do I assign this date to the fragment label.

Below is my fragment, the adapter and xml with the databinding onClick

````
class ShopDayFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentShopDayBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: GroceryViewModel
    private var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    private lateinit var dateSetListener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_shop_day,
            container,
            false
        )
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val database = GroceryDatabase.getInstance(application).groceryDatabaseDao
        val repository = GrocRepository(database)
        val factory = GroceryViewModelFactory(repository, application)


        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(GroceryViewModel::class.java)
        val adapter = GroceryDayAdapter(GroceryDayListener { id ->
            viewModel.onGroceryDayClicked(id)
        })

        binding.rvShopDay.adapter = adapter
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.groceryViewModel = viewModel

        viewModel.getAllGroceryDays().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })

        viewModel.navigateToListItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { groceryDay ->
            groceryDay?.let {
                
//                val bundle = bundleOf("id" to groceryDay)
//
//                this.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_shopDayFragment_to_listFragment, bundle)
//                viewModel.onListItemNavigated()


                val action = ShopDayFragmentDirections.actionShopDayFragmentToListFragment(groceryDay)
                this.findNavController().navigate(action)

            }
        })

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {

            DatePickerDialog(
                requireContext(),
                dateSetListener,
                cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            ).show()
        }

        dateSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            val myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            val date = sdf.format(cal.time).toString()
            val day = GroceryDay(0, date, 10.0)
            viewModel.upsert(day)
        }
    }
}```

class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentListBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: ListItemViewModel
    private var adapter = ListItemAdapter()
    private lateinit var day: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            day = it.getString("groceryDay").toString()
        }
    }
        val tv: TextView = binding.tvTest

        tv.text = day




```class GroceryDayAdapter(val clickListener: GroceryDayListener) :
    ListAdapter<GroceryDay, GroceryDayAdapter.GroceryViewHolder>(GroceryDayDiffCallBack()) {

    class GroceryViewHolder private constructor(val binding: AdapterShopDayBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val ivDelete: ImageView = binding.ivDelete

        fun bind(currDay: GroceryDay, clickListener: GroceryDayListener) {
            binding.groceryDay = currDay
            binding.clickListener = clickListener
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): GroceryViewHolder {
                val binding = AdapterShopDayBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
                return GroceryViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GroceryViewHolder {
        return from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GroceryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position)!!, clickListener)
    }
}

class GroceryDayDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<GroceryDay>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: GroceryDay, newItem: GroceryDay): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: GroceryDay, newItem: GroceryDay): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

class GroceryDayListener(val clickListener: (id: Int) -> Unit){
    fun onClick(groceryDay: GroceryDay) = clickListener(groceryDay.id)
}```

```  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> clickListener.onClick(groceryDay)}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">```
````

Comment: You're using `this.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_shopDayFragment_to_listFragment)` - that isn't passing any arguments at all to the other fragment. Is there a reason you aren't following the [Pass data between destinations guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) and using Safe Args or a `Bundle` to pass arguments?

Comment: I've tried to use SafeArgs but it can't find "by NavArgs()". I checked all the dependencies and pluggins versions and it seems to be alright. I also tried with Bundle but the object sent appears null on the textView. I have updated the code above

Comment: I'm confused. Your Bundle code is showing a key of "id" and passes in a `GroceryDay` object, but your code reading it is looking for a String with the key "groceryId"? It is `navArgs()`, not `NavArgs()` and part of the `-ktx` Navigation artifacts. Please include your `dependencies` block if you want help with not being able to find methods.

Comment: Check out the official tutorial: https://youtu.be/8I8Xykqn4hk